GitLab issues with "go get all" in nested repo
We're using GitLab Enterprise at gitlab.mycompany.net. We've created a Go library in a "subdirectory" space (whatever the correct term is), i.e. gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar/mylib.git.
Now, I have another Git project that needs to reference this library. So, in my go.mod I create a reference:
require (
  ...
  gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar/mylib v1.0.0
  ...
)

Now I run go mod tidy, and things break:
> go mod tidy
go: downloading gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar/mylib v1.0.0
reading gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar/mylib/go.mod at revision mylib/v1.0.0: git ls-remote -q origin in /blah/blah/path: exit status 128:
        remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
        fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar.git/' not found

That's dumb. There's no repo foo/bar.git; the repo is at foo/bar/mylib.git. But I did some research and found a workaround: in go.mod, I put:
replace gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar/mylib => gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar/mylib.git v1.0.0

That apparently gives the hint of where to look for the repo (though it's annoying that I have to say v1.0.0 explicitly again). So now go  mod tidy works. But weirdly, go get all is still failing, with the same error!
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
        fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.mycompany.net/foo/bar.git/' not found

What do I need to do to get go get all working?
